# REST login problem

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

I'm trying to log in to drupal8 via api rest using postman.

```
POST: https://example.com/user/login?_format=json
Content-type: application/json

{
"name": "admin",
"pass": "password"
}
```

The problem is that this error is returned to me.

> An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later, thanks.
>   Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\NotEncodableValueException: Syntax error in Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonDecode->decode() (line 78 of C:\www\drupal-composer\vendor\symfony\serializer\Encoder\JsonDecode.php).
>
> Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder->decode('', 'json', Array) (Line: 40)
>   Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\ChainDecoder->decode('', 'json', Array) (Line: 280)
>   Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer->decode('', 'json') (Line: 167)
>   Drupal\user\Controller\UserAuthenticationController->login(Object) call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
>   Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 582)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
>   Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
>   Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 151)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
>   Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
>   Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
>   Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 693)
>   Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Does anyone have a solution?
I am using Drupal 8.7.1.

Comment: Is the payload correct? The error thrown is `NotEncodableValueException`. See comment #4 in what you linked to.

Comment: Yes the payload is correct, obviously I have inserted some sample data.
Even trying with curl I get the same error.

Comment: The error stack is indicating that the $data is empty though

Comment: I'm trying to log-in following the official documentation here: 

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/javascript-and-drupal-8-restful-web-services#users

using postman with the correct payload and the correct endpoint, but nothing. Always the same error.

I also try other drupal installations, same mistake :-(

Comment: Solution found! Postman: method POST; endpoint: http://{your_url}/user/login?_format=json; section Header: Content-Type: application/json; section body: {
   "name": "admin","pass": "admin"}

Comment: @FabioMarsigliano you should answer your question and accept it in case somebody in the future has the same question.

Answer (score 4):

Solution found!
In Postman:

- method: **POST**
- endpoint: **http://{your_url}/user/login?_format=json**
- in section Header: **Content-Type: application/json**
- in section body: **{"name":"admin","pass": "admin"}**

Note: **name and password must be entered in the body section (raw)**

Comment: You just saved my life... i spent 4 hours already :D